# Why this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, apollo-client

I am trying to write a jest unit test for a react/typescript component but I keep getting the error

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

I definitely did not import/export incorrectly. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

My unit test file

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { DefaultTitleRenderer } from "./default-title-renderer"; // component that is failing
import { ApolloProvider } from "@test/frameworks-react-apollo";
import { createApolloClientMock } from "@test/utilities-test-apollo";
const mockClient = createApolloClientMock();

jest.mock("@test/components-1", () => ({
  use1Context: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock("@test/frameworks-react-apollo", () => ({
  useQuery: jest.fn(),
}));

describe("DefaultTitleRenderer", () => {
  it("renders the header title", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <ApolloProvider client={mockClient}>
        <DefaultTitleRenderer />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
    const pageHeader = getByTestId("example");
    expect(pageHeader).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

My DefaultTitleRenderer component

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  StyledText,
  Button,
  Tooltip,
} from "@test/components-fluent-ui";
import { exampleQuery } from "@test/data-resolvers-example";
import { useQuery } from "@test/frameworks-react-apollo";


export const DefaultTitleRenderer : React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const styles = styles();
  return (
    <div
      data-tid="example"
      className={styles.defaultHeader}
    >
      <HeaderTitle />
    </div>
  );
};

DefaultTitleRenderer.displayName = "DefaultTitleRenderer";

const HeaderTitle: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(exampleQuery, {
    partialRefetch: true,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    nextFetchPolicy: "cache-first",
  });

  const styles = someStyles();
  // more code here but not relevant
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Tooltip
        content={"Go Back"}
        data-tid="test"
        positioning="below"
        relationship="label"
        children={
          <Button
            icon={<ArrowStartIcon />}
            appearance="transparent"
            data-tid="test2"
            onClick={handleBackNavigation}
          ></Button>
        }
      />
      <StyledText
        weight="bold"
        data-tid="header"
        aria-hidden="true"
        className={styles.titleText}
      >
        {data}
      </StyledText>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, wrapping the DefaultTitleRenderer in the ApolloProvider made it return undefined. I removed the wrapper and just rendered my component and it resolved this issue.